# How to incorporate updated line colours into legend of a plot in R using lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

#### Context and Question:

I want to add a legend to a lattice plot in R that shows the density of two groups.
I've changed the default colours to black and gray. However, the legend has not updated the colours.

- How can I get the lattice plot to use my updated colours in the legend?
- How can I control the position of the legend (I'd like to be able to place it inside the plot area)?

#### Working example:

```
set.seed(4444)
x1 <- rep("Group A", 50)
x2 <- rep("Group B", 50)
y1 <- rnorm(50, 0, 2)
y2 <- rnorm(50, 1, 2)
dtf <- data.frame(x=c(x1, x2), y =c(y1, y2))

print(densityplot(~y, groups=x, data=dtf,
    pch=".",
    cex=2,
    col=c("black", "gray"),
    auto.key=TRUE,
    xlab="Y"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The legend color is a well-known annoyance in lattice. It looks like it is difficult to correct, because Deepayan recommends simpleTheme as a solution. For positioning, see Josh's answer.

```
print(densityplot(~y, groups=x, data=dtf,
              pch=".",
              cex=2,
              par.settings=simpleTheme(col=c("gray","black")),
              auto.key=TRUE,
              xlab="Y"))
```

Comment: +1 -- That's the nicer solution to setting the colors -- wrapping them in `simpleTheme()` -- that I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this works well enough. Notice that the `corner=` argument can be used to place the legend anywhere inside the plot.

```
densityplot(~y, groups = x, data = dtf,
    pch = ".",
    cex = 2,
    col = c("black", "gray"),
    par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col=c("black", "grey"))),
    auto.key = list(corner = c(0.95, 0.95)),
    xlab = "Y")
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer, and particularly the guidance on using `corner`.